# Generating all n-letter permutations

Tags: c++, performance, permutation

I am attempting to calculate all the possible 3 letter *permutations*, using the 26 letters (Which amounts to only 26*25*24=15,600). The order of the letters matters, and I don't want repeating letters.  (I wanted the permutations to be generated in lexicographical order, but that isn't necessary)

So far I attempted to nest `for` loops, but I ended up iterating through every *combination* possible. So there are repeating letters, which I do not want, and the `for` loops can become difficult to manage if I want more than 3 letters.

I can flip through the letters until I get a letter that has not been used, but it isn't in lexicographical order and it is *much* slower than using `next_permutation` (I cannot use this `std` method because I'm left calculating all of the subsets of the 26 letters).

Is there a more efficient way to do this?
To put in perspective of the inefficiency, `next_permutation` iterates through the first 6 digits instantaneously. However, it takes several seconds to get all the three letter permutations using this method, and `next_permutation` still quickly becomes inefficient with the 2^n subsets I must calculate.

Here is what I have for the nested `for` loops:

```
char key[] = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k',
'l','m','n','o','p','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};
bool used[25];
ZeroMemory( used, sizeof(bool)*25 );

for( int i = 0; i < 25; i++ )
{
     while( used[i] == true )
          i++;
     if( i >= 25 )
          break;
     used[i] = true;
     for( int j = 0; j < 25; j++ )
     {
          while( used[j] == true )
               j++;
          if( j >= 25 )
               break;
          used[j] = true;
          for( int k = 0; k < 25; k++ )
          {
               while( used[k] == true )
                    k++;
               if( k >= 25 )
                    break;
               used[k] = true;

               cout << key[i] << key[j] << key[k] << endl;

               used[k] = false;
          }
          used[j] = false;
     }
     used[i] = false;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a specific and small, n, manual loops like you have is the easiest way.  However, your code can be highly simplified:

```
for(char a='a'; a<='z'; ++a) {
    for(char b='a'; b<='z'; ++b) {
        if (b==a) continue;
        for(char c='a'; c<='z'; ++c) {
            if (c==a) continue;
            if (c==b) continue;
            std::cout << a << b << c << '\n';
        }
    }
}
```

For a variable N, obviously we need a different strategy.  And, it turns out, it needs an *incredibly* different strategy.  This is based on DaMachk's answer, of using recursion to generate subsequent letters

```
template<class func_type> 
void generate(std::string& word, int length, const func_type& func) {
    for(char i='a'; i<='z'; ++i) {
        bool used = false;
        for(char c : word) {
            if (c==i) {
                used = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (used) continue;
        word.push_back(i);
        if (length==1) func(word);
        else generate(word, length-1, func);
        word.pop_back();
    }
}
template<class func_type> 
void generate(int length, const func_type& func) {
    std::string word;
    generate(word, length, func);
}
```

[You can see it here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=81ea738fdecc06b23b7883084f9dd938-891c0cc722f784cfc9e99fda496cae8e)

I also made an unrolled version, which turned out to be incredibly complicated, but is significantly faster.  I have two helper functions: I have a function to "find the next letter" (called `next_unused`) which increases the letter at an index to the next unused letter, or returns `false` if it cannot.  The third function, `reset_range` "resets" a range of letters from a given index to the end of the string to the first unused letter it can. First we use `reset_range` to find the first string.  To find subsequent strings, we call `next_unused` on the last letter, and if that fails, the second to last letter, and if that fails the third to last letter, etc.  When we find a letter we can properly increase, we then "reset" all the letters to the right of that to the smallest unused values. If we get all the way to the first letter and it cannot be increased, then we've reached the end, and we stop.  The code is frightening, but it's the best I could figure out.

```
bool next_unused(char& dest, char begin, bool* used) {
    used[dest] = false;
    dest = 0;
    if (begin > 'Z') return false;
    while(used[begin]) {
        if (++begin > 'Z')
            return false;
    }
    dest = begin;
    used[begin] = true;
    return true;
}
void reset_range(std::string& word, int begin, bool* used) {
    int count = word.size()-begin;
    for(int i=0; i<count; ++i)
        assert(next_unused(word[i+begin], 'A'+i, used));
}
template<class func_type>
void doit(int n, func_type func) {
    bool used['Z'+1] = {};
    std::string word(n, '\0');
    reset_range(word, 0, used);
    for(;;) {
        func(word);
        //find next word
        int index = word.size()-1;
        while(next_unused(word[index], word[index]+1, used) == false) {
            if (--index < 0)
                return; //no more permutations
        }
        reset_range(word, index+1, used);
   }
}
```

[Here it is at work](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=14e511c11c985d3e3dd222e10ffb8cd6-891c0cc722f784cfc9e99fda496cae8e).
[And here it is running in a quarter of the time as the simple one](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=5b0de3d81a228ed927985f6bee085ae4-891c0cc722f784cfc9e99fda496cae8e)

Answer (score 6):

1. Make a root which represents the start of a combination, so it has no value.
2. calculate all the possible children (26 letter, 26 children...)
3. for each root child calculate possible children (so: remaining letters)
4. use a recursive limited-depth search to find your combinations.

Answer (score 4):

This is a solution I would try if i just want a "simple" solution. I'm not sure how recource intensive this is so I suggest you start trying with a small set of letters.

```
a = {a...z}
b = {a...z}
c = {a...z}

for each(a)
{
  for each(b)
  {
    for each(c)
    {
     echo a + b + c;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Well i don't know for sure if there is a better answer. Just trying to say that it probaly (well i should have said 'mabey') is not the best answer.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, English is not my native language so I am open to suggestions!

Comment: you don't really need three arrays, you could cut it down to just 1 and do an index-based loop instead of `for each`

Comment: I can't have repeating letters, but this could work by having each for loop containing a while loop before the nested for loop that will continue incrementing it until it finds an unused letter. I'll see if it works.

Comment: @MooingDuck I like the use of continue instead of a while loop, that fixed the problem of overwriting the stack, which I just patched by having it check if its too high and then breaking the loop. This is MUCH faster than what I had, thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

I was doing a similar thing in powershell. Generating all the possible combinations of 9 symbols. After a bit of trial and error this is what I came up with.

```
$S1=New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
$S1.Add("a")
$S1.Add("b")
$S1.Add("c")
$S1.Add("d")
$S1.Add("e")
$S1.Add("f")
$S1.Add("g")
$S1.Add("h")
$S1.Add("i")
$S1 | % {$a = $_
    $S2 = $S1.Clone()
    $S2.Remove($_)
    $S2 | % {$b = $_
        $S3 = $S2.Clone()
        $S3.Remove($_)
        $S3 | % {$c = $_
            $S4 = $S2.Clone()
            $S4.Remove($_)
            $S4 | % {$d = $_
                $S5 = $S4.Clone()
                $S5.Remove($_)
                $S5 | % {$e = $_
                    $S6 = $S5.Clone()
                    $S6.Remove($_)
                    $S6 | % {$f = $_
                        $S7 = $S6.Clone()
                        $S7.Remove($_)
                        $S7 | % {$g = $_
                            $S8 = $S7.Clone()
                            $S8.Remove($_)
                            $S8 | % {$h = $_
                                $S9 = $S8.Clone()
                                $S9.Remove($_)
                                $S9 | % {$i = $_
                                    ($a+$b+$c+$d+$e+$f+$g+$h+$i)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```